# Substitute list of strings in JSON file

Tags: json, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to substitute a list of Json strings from a dumped json file.

```
to_clean_up = [web-app,servlet-one,init-param, servlet-mapping]

stringify = json.dumps(data)

for i in to_clean_up:
    regex = re.sub(r'[^\w]','_', i)
    for m in stringify:
        m.replace(i,regex)
```

So im trying to substitute there words in the stringify , but, my stringify somehow stays the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs on `str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace), this method returns a *new* string without modifying the original.

You should do something like this:

```
for j, m in enumerate(stringify):
    stringify[i] = m.replace(i, regex)
```

Moreover, in this loop `m` will be a single character, so I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here... You could as well do `stringify = stringify.replace(i, regex)`.